# How does typical data flow look like when handling large scale API requests and stream processing using Kafka and Cassandra?

Tags: apache-kafka, cassandra

I am trying to understand large scale request processing and the flow of data involved for same. I believe i have some sense of the components involved but i do not have practical knowledge on putting the components together.

**Hypothetical Scenario**

- We are building a system to provide sentiment prediction given an input sentence.
- There are millions of concurrent users who will consume the system via API giving a combination of two fields `id` and `inputSentence`.
- The system will use a ML model to predict the sentiment
- And the users will be able to query back the sentiment result via APIs passing the `id` parameter to the endpoint.

For such a system, would the backend flow look like one of the following?

**Option 1**

1. Customer sends input data via API interface (POST)
2. The API produces the input into Kafka
3. Kafka consumer (or stream) takes the input, generates ML prediction and stores it into Cassandra
4. Customer is served responses from Cassandra (GET). However the Customer sees a 404 response until the data is processed and available in Cassandra.
5. For internal offline analysis, dump data from Cassandra and use Spark to run batch processing jobs

**Option 2**

1. Customer sends input data via API interface (POST)
2. The API stores the record first into Cassandra. And we use some mechanism (CDC?) to produces the new record into Kafka
3. Kafka consumer (or stream) takes the input, generates ML prediction and updates it back into Cassandra
4. Customer is served responses from Cassandra (GET). He is able to see status of record even when it is yet to be processed via Kafka (Step 3).
5. For internal offline analysis, dump data from Cassandra and use Spark to run batch processing jobs

**Question 1**
As seen above, my confusion is about whether Kafka comes first or Cassandra comes first when we ingest the request from the API. Mainly because it seems to impact whether the Customer is able to GET the request while its under processing.

Coming from typical API + relational database background, `Option 2` seems somewhat natural where we record the request in the database and then process it. Also, in this scenario, the customer is able to poll for the status and see some kind of `PENDING` status for his input request. However setting up CDC for Cassandra seem to be an additional component which i am not sure is necessary.

In `Option 1` it looks like Customer will not know the status of his record (404) until some time has passed by. Which feels a bit odd to me.

**Question 2**
How are failures in message processing handled? Specifically, ones caused by incorrect-handling (bad code). Say some request is causing the ML prediction step to fail. Would we typically put this message in a separat topic and trigger an alert to the team for them to investigate? Are there better techniques considering we may get many error alerts?

Would be great if folks who have implemented such large scale systems can provide some insights.